# Differences between `.EditingDidEnd` and `.EditingDidEndOnExit`

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit, uicontrolevents

What exactly are the differences between the `UIControlEvents` `.EditingDidEnd` and `.EditingDidEndOnExit`, and how do they relate to each other?

The [documentation on UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events) is pretty vague, and has no information of whether these fire for different reasons, if one is a superset of the other, or if they're functionally equivalent.

The possibility of one being a superset is especially confusing, since the naming implies that `.EditingDidEndOnExit` is a specific occurrence of `.EditingDidEnd`, but the documentation seems to imply the opposite.

Answer (score 35):

"`.EditingDidEnd`" is called when somebody touches outside of the bounds of the text field, because they're likely about to interact with some other control or object.

"`EditingDidEndOnExit`" is called when the user clicks the "`return`" key in the keyboard (and you're right, it's not clear in the documentation... but if you look at the UIControl.h file you'll see a comment reflecting this point).

Comment: `EditingDidEndOnExit` does dismiss the keyboard. But `EditingDidEnd` seems dismiss if I click in another text field, but not in any-other location (off-a-field)

Comment: If I have a UITextField with both, I see tapping the `return` triggering both... like `EditingDidEndOnExit; EditingDidEnd`. When I add logging to wrap the target action, they seem to be run on separate threads, because the output is interlaced.

Answer (score 9):

From the UIControl header:

```
UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing
```

So one is when the return key was pressed, the other is from touching outside of the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

When a user taps on the return key of the keyboard, the following events are executed in order:

- editingDidEndOnExit
- primaryActionTriggered
- editingDidEnd

When a user taps another UITextField or UITextView object, only 'editingDidEnd' is executed.

When app code executes 'resignFirstResponder()' on a given UITextField, only 'editingDidEnd' is executed.

When app code executes 'endEditing(true|false)' on a given UITextField, only 'editingDidEnd' is executed.

When app code executes 'becomeFirstResponder()' on another UITextField, only 'editingDidEnd' is executed.

When a user taps on the return key of the keyboard and textField has a delegate, the following events are executed in order:

- delegate: textFieldShouldReturn
- editingDidEndOnExit
- primaryActionTriggered
- editingDidEnd
- delegate: textFieldDidEndEditing

Keyboard will dismiss if one or both following events will be supported:

- textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingDidEndOnExit), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
- textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(primaryActionTriggered), for: .primaryActionTriggered)

Checked on iOS 16.2